# any stl/boost functors to call operator()

Tags: c++, boost, stl

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    void operator()(T& t) { t(); }
};
```

Is there any standart or boost functor with the similar implementation?

I need it to iterate over container of functors:

```
std::for_each(beginIter, endIter, Foo<Bar>());
```

Or maybe there are other way to do it?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for. What is wrong with your code as-is? What is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: I have container of boost::function objects. I wish to iterate over it with std::for_each and call operator() for every boost::function element;
I'm intrested whether the functor like Foo is already implemented in stl/boost.  Of course it's not a big deal to write it. Just thought it could be already implemented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binders like Boosts or C++0x `bind()` make it trivial to generate such a functor:

```
std::for_each(begin, end, boost::bind(&Bar::operator(), _1));
```

Or using `mem_fun_ref`:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::mem_fun_ref(&Bar::operator()));
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be slightly less wordy with `BOOST_FOREACH`, especially if you have C++0x's auto support:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(auto f, v) {f();}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least i found it. boost::apply should do all the job

```
std::for_each(beginIter, endIter, boost::bind(boost::apply<void>(), _1));
```